# puppet dashboard: format mismatch while importing reports

Tags: puppet-dashboard

a brand-new puppet-dashboard 2.0.0-beta1 can't import any reports: delayed_job workers complain:

```
Importing report at 2015-10-01 04:55 UTC
  Attribute was supposed to be a Array, but was a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  Backtrace
    app/models/report.rb:134:in `create_from_yaml'
```

puppet client version is: 4.2.2

It looks a format mismatch, but the only 'format' directive I find is:

```
preferred_serialization_format = pson
```

The dashboard logs are simply:

```
2015-10-01T08:09:16+0200: [Worker(delayed_job.1 host:puppet pid:19415)] Class#create_from_yaml completed after 0.0752
2015-10-01T08:09:16+0200: [Worker(delayed_job.1 host:puppet pid:19415)] 1 jobs processed at 11.1567 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of october 2015, in order to have puppet-dashboard to accept reports in the puppet4 format, you have to fetch the pull request #329.

That solved my issue.